# Network Subnetting

Tags: networking, subnet, small-business-server

Just trying to understand network subnetting a little better. I have been given a problem in dividing a network using IP 10.0.0.0/8 into 5 department units with 200 computers each. What would the IP table ranges look like?

Comment: See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499).

Comment: @ron maupin is right. This is an excellent answer if you are confused about subneting. If you read that explanation, and still can't make heads or tails of it. I would suggest a subnet calculator. Although It really is best if you have a full grasp on the concept in your head

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this.

Absent further requirements I would be inclined to simply break this into a number of subnets, each with about 65534 useable addresses. I'd do this by using the second octet to define the department - thus

10.1.x.x. Would be Dept 1
10.2.x.x would be Dept 2
.
.

In this case you would specify a netmask of 255.255.0.0 - meaning the first 2 digits are not changeable and define the dept, and there can be over 300 depts eventually set up, and the 2 rightmost digits mean up to 65k users per dept.

Comment: Interesting, I would have gone with a /23 or a /24 based off of the total devices in each subnet. 65000 addresses seems like quite a large subnet for the requirements.

Comment: There is no right or wrong way if doing this, and certainly a /23 is practical. My reasons for preferring a /16 is it makes identifying the department easy. It also makes it easy if later on a department wants to split off a chunk for its own servers or whatever. The 10.x.x.x subnet is good like that.  Of-course the limitation of my addressing choice means it's a bit harder to expand to multiple regions, being that there is less flexibility on the second octet.

Comment: I didn't mean to detract from your post. I somewhat agree with you, without knowing where the OP's organization is headed as far as expansion or future plans, it would be conjecture to say anything is right or wrong. I just find it interesting the way that other people solve the same  problems differently, and sometimes it's even eye opening. Cheers